# how to create an array of specified dimension of specific type initialized with same value in python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I wanna create some array in python of array of specified dimension of specific type initialized with same value. i can use numpy arrays of specific size but I am not sure how to initialize them with a specific value. Off course I don't want to use zeros() or ones()

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this. The first one-liner that occurred to me is `tile`:

```
>>> numpy.tile(2, 25)
array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

You can tile a value in any shape:

```
>>> numpy.tile(2, (5, 5))
array([[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

However, as a number of answers below indicate, this isn't the fastest method. It's designed for tiling arrays of any size, not just single values, so if you really just want to fill an array with a single value, then it's much faster to allocate the array first, and then use slice assignment:

```
>>> a = numpy.empty((5, 5), dtype=int)
>>> a[:] = 2
>>> a
array([[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

According to a few tests I did, there aren't any faster approaches. However, two of the approaches mentioned in answers below are equally fast: [`ndarray.fill`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6959641/577088) and [`numpy.full`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24175419/577088).

These tests were all done in `ipython`, using Python 3.6.1 on a newish mac running OS 10.12.6. Definitions:

```
def fill_tile(value, shape):
    return numpy.tile(value, shape)

def fill_assign(value, shape, dtype):
    new = numpy.empty(shape, dtype=dtype)
    new[:] = value
    return new

def fill_fill(value, shape, dtype):
    new = numpy.empty(shape, dtype=dtype)
    new.fill(value)
    return new

def fill_full(value, shape, dtype):
    return numpy.full(shape, value, dtype=dtype)

def fill_plus(value, shape, dtype):
    new = numpy.zeros(shape, dtype=dtype)
    new += value
    return new

def fill_plus_oneline(value, shape, dtype):
    return numpy.zeros(shape, dtype=dtype) + value

for f in [fill_assign, fill_fill, fill_full, fill_plus, fill_plus_oneline]:
    assert (fill_tile(2, (500, 500)) == f(2, (500, 500), int)).all()
```

`tile` is indeed quite slow:

```
In [3]: %timeit fill_tile(2, (500, 500))
947 µs ± 10.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Slice assignment ties with `ndarray.fill` and `numpy.full` for first place:

```
In [4]: %timeit fill_assign(2, (500, 500), int)
102 µs ± 1.37 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit fill_fill(2, (500, 500), int)
102 µs ± 1.99 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [6]: %timeit fill_full(2, (500, 500), int)
102 µs ± 1.47 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

In-place broadcasted addition is only slightly slower:

```
In [7]: %timeit fill_plus(2, (500, 500), int)
179 µs ± 3.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

And non-in-place broadcasted addition is only slightly slower than that:

```
In [8]: %timeit fill_plus_oneline(2, (500, 500), int)
213 µs ± 4.74 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks, how does it work for Nd? I want to pass the arguments generically and i don't want to use the function reshape afterwords

Comment: @Shan, did you look at my second example?

Comment: @senderler, yes  i did, it works, thanks for answer... I wanna accept the answer but it will take 6 more minutes.

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
shape = (100,100)
val = 3.14
dt = np.float
a = np.empty(shape,dtype=dt)
a.fill(val)
```

This way you can set things and pass the parameters in. Also, in terms of timings

```
In [35]: %timeit a=np.empty(shape,dtype=dt); a.fill(val)
100000 loops, best of 3: 13 us per loop

In [36]: %timeit a=np.tile(val,shape)
10000 loops, best of 3: 102 us per loop
```

So using `empty` with `fill` seems significantly faster than `tile`.

Comment: yes this will also work but the solution proposed by senderle is easier and works... your is more elegant in terms of parameters and correctness.

Comment: @Shan, no problem (and if you found it useful and the better solution, please upvote and mark it as the correct answer).

Comment: @ JoshAdel, now i am confused which answer to select... i have already accepted the answer... Yours seem to be efficient.

Comment: @JoshAdel, it's not clear to me that these differ significantly in terms of parameters -- tile just infers the dtype from the type of the argument, which you can make explicit by passing `numpy.int64(x)` or whatever. But the speedup is potentially significant, depending on the use case; there appears to be a small tradeoff between readability and speed here. +1 -- I'm glad to know that. @Shan, you should accept whichever answer meets your needs. I won't be offended if you accept this answer instead :)

Comment: @senderle, in terms of passing parameters, they are essentially identical as you say. I only emphasized setting them external to the function calls since the OP mentioned it. I don't know if my solution is really less readable than yours though.

Answer (score 3):

As of NumPy 1.8, you can use `numpy.full()` to achieve this.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.full((3,4), 100, dtype = int)
array([[ 100,  100,  100,  100],
       [ 100,  100,  100,  100],
       [ 100,  100,  100,  100]])
```

Comment: Looks like a 2x speedup over `np.zeros((N,M),dtype=int)+100`

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
>>> [3 for x in range(10)]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

You can pass the resulting array to [`numpy.array`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html).

Comment: No, list comprehensions don't give numpy arrays.